# Нелокализованные сообщения для новых пользователей

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Советую переводчикам пройтись по следующему сценарию:

1. зарегистрироваться;
2. задать вопрос.

Количество надписей на английском во всяких подсказках ужасающее. По-моему, с этим надо срочно разобраться.

[image]

[image]

Это я прокликал по самым первым ссылкам на сайте, которые видит новичок. Я уж молчу про то, что можно увидеть, если вчитываться...

См. тж. [Инструкция по переводу интерфейса сайта на главной странице справочного центра — зачем?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/605)

Comment: Ну хотя бы скриншот был бы полезен :-)

Comment: @VladD Добавил скриншоты.

Comment: Не нашёл этих строк в транзифексе. Так что вопрос «уходит» администрации.

Comment: @VladD Сопутствующий вопрос: на кой икс на главной странице справки инструкция по переводу? Это последнее, что там должно быть.

Comment: @Discord: Может быть, стоит перенести из комментария в вопрос? Или правильнее наверное задать отдельным вопросом.

Comment: @VladD Этот вопрос присутствует в скриншоте... Ну, могу в отдельный вопрос вынести...

Comment: А, точно, есть на скриншоте. Тогда лучше наверное не плодить сущности?

Comment: @VladD Раскидал вопросы, они всё-таки про разные вещи: одно про вики-справку, другое про транзифекс. Кстати, "сводка" в транзифексе всё-таки должна быть, она же переведена. Там ошибка в том, что вообще-то имеется в виду "тур".

Comment: @Discord: Сводку вижу в транзифексе, 3 штуки: info, about и summary. Интересно, какая это из них? (А куда ведёт ссылка?)

Comment: Ага, это about.

Comment: @Discord: Тогда, вероятно, надо перевести как «о сайте»?

Comment: @VladD Э... Вообще-то "сводка" — это ссылка на тур, как я уже сказал.

Comment: @Discord: Ну, не смотря на это, на английском она называется about. Может быть, в этом есть резон?

Comment: @VladD Можно и "о сайте", не принципиально. Но не какая-то "сводка".

Comment: @Discord: Ну, ошибка перевода без контекста, что поделать? Сейчас поправлю. UPD: поправил.

Comment: Прошёлся, нигде непереведённых строк не нашёл. Если все-таки есть где-то, то сообщайте с конкретным скриншотом.