# Инструкция по переводу интерфейса сайта на главной странице справочного центра — зачем?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Идём на [ru.stackoverflow.com/help](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/) и видим:

> Мы верим, что ни одна компания-переводчик не сделает интерфейс пользователя понятнее, приятнее и проще, чем сообщество! Если вы хотите присоединиться к тем избранным, которые устанавливают терминологию русскоязычного сообщества программистов и системных администраторов, пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь формой обратной связи. Будем рады видеть ваш отклик. Создадим наш островок Знаний вместе!
>
> #### Зачем нужен коллективный перевод?
>
> 1. Перевод - отчасти творческое занятие. В сообществе мы используем много непрямых переводов с английского, например, “flag” -> “тревога”, в то время как большинство переводит это слово просто как “флаг”. Чем больше творческих людей, обладающих литературным языком, примет участие, тем более “русскоязычным” будет перевод, а как результат - форумом будет приятнее пользоваться.
> 2. Коллективное редактирование поможет исключить ошибки, которые один человек добавил бы в дополнение к уже существующим.
> 3. Скорость такого перевода намного быстрее.
>
> #### Рекомендации
>
> Работая над переводом, мы стараемся использовать как можно более литературный язык, по возможности избегать заимствованных слов. По нашему мнению, такой перевод позволяет быстрее разобраться в сложном функционале сайта и предоставляет лучший опыт пользователю.
>
> Переводя сообщения об ошибках, подобные "An error occurred during submission", следует указывать причину ошибки в начале сообщения. То есть, *Верно*: "При отправке возникла ошибка", _неверно__: "Возникла ошибка при отправке".

Что это? Зачем это там?

Между прочим, это одна из первых страниц, которые видит новичок. Это вход в Справочный центр — хранилище информации для благовоспитанных юзеров. И тут им в рожу кидают: *"Переводя сообщения об ошибках, подобные "An error occurred during submission", следует указывать причину ошибки в начале сообщения".* Да ладно?

Вдобавок, там ещё и косяки с форматированием.

[image]

Comment: Перенес публикации на [Мету](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Избранные уже набраны и отправились за своим Генератором Эдемских Кущ Компактным. Согласен, что текст этот пора убирать. Например, его можно переместить на Мету под названием "Как принять участие в переводе сайта?"

UPD: Уж полночь близится, а Германа всё нет.

Comment: Оформление в виде `кода` следует использовать только для идентификаторов и небольших кусочков кода. В других случаях подобное выделение избыточно (в частности, в случае названий и заголовков).

Comment: @Discord тут бы отлично смотрелось оформление в виде ссылки на уже существующий вопрос. =)

Comment: @Discord, а курсивом ключевые слова можно выделять?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Собственно, em/i — *emphasis*, strong/b — **strong emphasis**. То есть по смыслу, как и в обычном тексте. Только не следует злоупотрелблять, как я. :)

Comment: @Discord знаю я одного пользователя, который запросто использует полужирный внутри кода внутри кавычек внутри цитаты. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/2790048

Comment: @Discord, спасибо, записал в оба блокнота. («а если у вас, рядовой, голова дырявая, то заведите блокнот! а лучше два, *как я*!»)